# What are the basic, fundamental concepts of logarithms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Soon I will be learning of logarithms, but I wish to have a head start over my class mates or at least a fair greeting to the concept. I would appreciate a very clear-cut answer with very straight to the point examples, an answer like this and with steps would be tremendously helpful and quickly voted best answer. Some specific questions on which to base your answer could be: why are they used? What is an example of a simple logarithm? how do you solve one?, and how does it apply to quadratic equations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For one, the two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: So, you want someone to write a book on logarithms. Guess what: dozens of such books have already been written! There are probably a few at a library near you! There may even be a textbook for the course you are going to do! That's where to start --- enjoy!

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm).

Comment: do you realize i have no idea what they are, but i only know we will be learning about them in class soon?

Comment: @Zev, they do a lot more than sound similar --- each is an anagram of the other! But, of course, you are quite correct.

Comment: There you are people, the question is now, What are logarithms.

Comment: Its a beat made by musical trees...

Comment: Logarithms convert multiplication into addition just as $10^5 = 10^2 \cdot 10^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often in math you want to know what power you have to raise $b$ to in order to get $x$ as a result:
\begin{equation}
b^? = x.
\end{equation}
This question is so basic that it comes up all the time.
The answer to this question is called the logarithm (base $b$) of $x$.

For example, $10$ to what power is $1000$?  The answer is $\log_{10}(1000) = 3$.

The name "logarithm" is undescriptive and intimidating.  A more descriptive name might be "the exponent from $b$ to $x$."
\begin{equation}
\log_b(x) = \text{the exponent from } b \text{ to } x.
\end{equation}

Comment: so basically, a person uses a base and finds what exponent goes on that base in order to get what x equals. is that correct? if solved in this way it would seem that logarithms are useless because how are you suppose to find out what the best base is to use and usually you don't know what x is.   Ohhhh, so you use them in conjunction with factoring or other methods of solving for x?

Answer (score 2):

A large part of mathematics is devoted to finding solutions to some equation. Given $y$ find $x$ such that:
$$
f(x) = y.
$$

This is accomplished by finding (or getting information about) the inverse of the function $f$. When $f$ contains a power function $a^b$ you are required to invert the power operation. When you want to solve for the base $x^b = y$ the inverse is the $b$-th root function $x=\sqrt[b]{y}$. When you want to invert with respect to the exponent $a^x = y$ the inverse function is called logarithm: $x=\log_a y$.

Notice that since $a^b$ can be written as $e^{b\log_e a}$ (this you will learn, but you can find yourself if you work a little bit), every power can be expressed by means of the exponential function $\exp(x) = e^x$ where $e$ is a fixed number. 
So every power and inverse of a power can be written by means of exponential and logarithmic functions.

Logarithm were historically very important because they convert multiplications into sums (as exponentiation converts sums into products):
$$
 \log(a\cdot b) = \log a + \log b
$$
and powers into multiplications:
$$
  \log (a^b) = b \log a.
$$

Hence if you have a tool to compute logarithms (in any fixed base) you are able to simplify this kind of computations. The tools used (before calculators) were the [logarithmic tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_table#Tables_of_logarithms) and the [slide rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule).